# How to query items in mongodb with a particular dictionary including at least one non zero value?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have the following item structure:

```
"_id": "12325523623453254",
  "blas": {
    "blaA": 0,
    "blaB": 0,
    "blaC": 0,
    "blaD": 1,
  }
}
```

I like to find the items with "blas" including at least one non zero value.

Comment: are blaA, blaB, blaC, blaD fixed attributes of blas?? or it can have any number of attributes?

Comment: it is fixed as defined

Comment: Then it is a case of $or operator as shown in JohnnyHK's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or) query that uses dot notation in the keys to access the fields within `blas`:

```js
db.test.find({$or: [
    {'blas.blaA': {$ne: 0}},
    {'blas.blaB': {$ne: 0}},
    {'blas.blaC': {$ne: 0}},
    {'blas.blaD': {$ne: 0}}
]})
```